# Is there a way to generate a link on Android and iOS that opens in Firefox if installed and, if not, directs to AppStore/GooglePlay to install FF

Tags: android, ios, firefox

I'm developing a web application called klank.dev that only works on Firefox. If someone tries to use klank.dev on a mobile phone, I would like klank.dev to open in Firefox if installed *or* direct the person to the App Store/Google Play to download Firefox and then ideally have the link opened in Firefox automatically once downloaded. Is this sort of flow possible?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: AFAIK you can check if you have an APK installed on the device using PackageManager if I'm not mistaking. If it's not installed, I'm quite sure you can direct the user to Google playStore to fireFox installation page. You can then listen to packages being installed on the device and check if a new package is installed, being FireFox, open the link the user previously wanted. I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't know all the code needed for it, but this should be the flow possible, at least for android

Comment: This code checks for installed packages: private static boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, PackageManager packageManager) {
        try {
            packageManager.getPackageInfo(packagename, 0);
            return true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

Comment: This is definitely helpful, but the snag here is that klank.dev is a web application, so I don't have access to Swift or Java APIs, just plain old JS in a browser.

Comment: Oh, I see, in that case I don't know much. I do remember reading somewhere though that it's not possible for you to even see permissions given to an app on the device so I'd say I'd assume it's not possible to do so in your environment. I might be wrong of course, this is just an assumption